# SELECT statement of data from table depending on one field

Tags: mysql, sql, join, if-statement

There is a sql statement that returns valueable information from this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de457/3)

```
CREATE TABLE `civil`(
      civil_id      INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      name          VARCHAR(25)  ,
      address_civil VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL ,
      telephone     VARCHAR(20 ) NOT NULL ,
      email         VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL ,
      comment       VARCHAR(35 )  NOT NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_civil` UNIQUE (`civil_id`)           
);

CREATE TABLE `worker`(
      worker_id      INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      name           VARCHAR(25)  ,
      address_worker VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL ,
      departament    VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL ,
      age            INTEGER  NOT NULL ,      
      CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_civil` UNIQUE (`worker_id`)           
);

CREATE TABLE `event`(
      id_event      INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      type_event    VARCHAR(25)  ,
      personID        INT  NOT NULL ,
      date          DATE NOT NULL ,   
      isWorker INT NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_event` UNIQUE (`id_event`)           
);

ALTER TABLE `event` ADD INDEX (personID);

INSERT INTO `civil` VALUES (  1, 'JOE','SOME ADDRESS', '5646464','joe@gms.com','no comment' );
INSERT INTO `civil` VALUES (  2, 'MOE','SOME ADDRESS', '6776543','froe@ges.com','no comment' );

INSERT INTO `worker` VALUES (  1, 'MARGE','STATES W54', 'finances',34);
INSERT INTO `worker` VALUES (  2, 'SASHA','LIVER S 34', 'sells',23 );

INSERT INTO `event` VALUES (1,"type1", 1, '12-12-12',1);
```

doing

```
SELECT  a.*,
        IF(a.Isworker = 1,c.name, b.name) AS personname
FROM    event a
        LEFT JOIN civil b
            ON a.personid = b.civil_id
        LEFT JOIN worker c
            ON a.personid = c.worker_ID
```

returns

```
ID_EVENT TYPE_EVENT PERSONID DATE                   ISWORKER PERSONNAME
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   type1   1   December, 12 2012 00:00:00+0000        1    MARGE
```

How can I get all data (not just name) of civil and worker table depending on the field isworker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably recommend re-structuring / better normalizing your tables...  But just working with what you have, one option would be to add your isworker check to the join statement.  Other than that, you'd have to find comparable fields between civilian and worker to cancel each other out in an `IF()` statement like you used for personname.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    event a
        LEFT JOIN civil b
            ON a.personid = b.civil_id
            AND a.Isworker != 1
        LEFT JOIN worker c
            ON a.personid = c.worker_ID
            AND a.Isworker = 1
```

Comment: And How could I get rid of Nulls ? Is there a way to avoid them?

Comment: That's where you'd have to use an `IF()` statement like you did for personname.  So for example, you'd have `select IF(a.Isworker = 1,c.name, b.name) AS personname, IF(a.Isworker = 1,c.address_civil, b.address_worker) AS address,...` and so on.

Comment: Since `SELECT *` is frowned upon, if you explicitly select the fields you want you can avoid the extra nulls by using `COALESCE()` see [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: @Daniel...two unrelated points there.  Good point on SELECT * -- I wasn't sure if that would cause MySQL to ignore the index / do a tablescan, but I do know you can use FORCE INDEX to avoid that problem (and still use the asterisk).  As for COALESCE -- nothing to do with SELECT *, but could be used in place of the IF statement (no real gain or loss to be had though).